# Reflecting impedance in a transformer

Tags: ac, transformer, impedance, impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance

Please can anyone tell me what exactly is meant by reflecting of impedance in a transformer?

I do not know much about transformers, but I want to know about its uses and phenomena behind it.

I will be using a current transformer in my project to find out the impedance reflection. I do know the formula to find out how much impedance is being reflected, but do not understand the theoretical concept involved in it.

Comment: Might this question be related to RF and standing waves and using a current transformer like how they are used in a VSWR meter?

Comment: i am actually doing a energy meter with anti power theft hence for that purpose i required this concept

Answer (score 4):

Its the 'equivalent load' you would have to connect across the **primary voltage**  in order to produce the same value of current that would flow in the primary of a transformer due to a load connected  to the secondary.

The basic theoretical concepts are:

(1) Transformer turns ratios
(2) Power conservation (power out = power in) 
(3) Ohm's law

[image]

An example:

Suppose you had a 10:1 turns **reduction** transformer and put 100V on the primary. The output voltage would be 1/10 of 100 i.e. 10 V. If you were to connect a 10 ohm load across the secondary this would produce a secondary current of 1 Amp. (Ohm's law). Assuming the transformer is 100% efficient then the power out must equal the power in. This means the primary current will be 1/10th the secondary current or 0.1 amps. So at the primary side we have 100V and a current of 0.1 amps.

If the transformer circuit was replaced by a single equivalent load then by Ohm's law this would be equal to 100V / 0.1A = 1000 ohms. This is the reflected impedance of the 10 ohm load on the secondary.

Comment: I've asked the op if in fact this is more of an RF question related VSWR stuff rather than normal transformer theory. Just a heads up dude.

Comment: @Andyaka cheers m8