# Can I decrease AC voltage and increase current in a AC converter?

Tags: ac, transformer

Can I decrease voltage and increase current for my circuit?

Suppose there's an input source of 12V 1A AC. Can I change it to 1V 10A AC with a step down transformer? Can this be achieved in another way? Please explain it in simple terms since I haven't got good knowledge about Electrical Engineering.

Comment: Please don't use an ALL-CAPS title.

Comment: You already mentioned a transformer, which does just that. Though, there is always a trade off, as you said, one goes up the other must come down. The power (V*I) remains the same or lower (efficiency). There are other configurations, buck or boost converter for example.

Comment: Recommend closing question as it's extremely low quality.

Comment: so it means that it is possible to make 12v 1a ac to 1v 10a ac right with transformer ?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189761/how-can-we-have-high-voltage-and-low-current-in-transformers-if-v-i-imped

Comment: I don't agree that this question is unclear. OK, the title is IN ALL CAPS, and the english is not 100%, but anyone should be able to make out what is asked. At least EM Fields did.

Comment: You could use a voltage regulator to get constant voltage output from an arbitrary input voltage within a fairly wide range. Pololu has a bunch [here](https://www.pololu.com/category/133/step-up-step-down-voltage-regulators); I have the S18V20ALV model and it works pretty well for loads in excess of 1A, as long as your source can supply the required power. (With very heavy loads, you may need to cool the regulator itself to avoid overheating.)

Comment: @DragonLord: The OP is asking about AC, not DC.

Comment: Ah... That would call for a transformer.

Comment: @Wouter: Yes, it's not too hard to figure out what the OP is asking.  However, the question is so low quality and so annoying that giving this guy what he wants would be bad for the site.  We don't want him coming back and writing more crap like this.  "Crap" isn't one of the official close reasons, so people use "unclear".  Unfortunately EMFields and Ricardo just don't get it, so we'll probably see more of this in the future.  Sigh.

Comment: @Olin his English might be more than bad, but he did give all the info required to answer. And I gather that he is a total newby in electronics, so that is a good start. I'd rather see (and answer) this type of question than the type in perfect english that requires a crystal ball to answer, or the 'design this for me, right now' type.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, while I agree somewhat, I also think a community of any sort should welcome newbies. English may not be his/her first language, I don't think we should penalize for that, and the question may only be low quality because of their lack of knowledge. Being too elitest is a bad quality for a community.

Comment: Technical communities have a really hard time embracing beginners. It is important to note the difference between someone who hasn't done research to try and answer question (down voting suggested) and someone who isn't smart/experienced/knowledgable (no crime there).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the answer is yes.

12 volts times 1 ampere available from your source is 12 watts, so as long as the voltage times the current into the load doesn't exceed 12 watts, you can use a transformer to get any current and/or voltage you want into the load.

There are limitations, of course, but that's probably not important yet.